# JFreeChart grid base axis

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart 1.0.14 in Swing application.
I have chart with multiple Y-Axis and I want to change source Axis for chart grid lines. Now them always base on one axis, even if I hide it.

I know there are few similar questions but they are old and I wonder if solution exists now.

If it doesn't what is the best workaround in this task?

For example: 
http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27885&sid=c4c609f3809d29a46e3e2bbccfac361e

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117520).

Comment: Yes because I think no one knows answer on official forum. But after I create this thread library creator answered to me. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also edit your question with updates, and you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still no way to do it natively unfortunately.
I was suggested to override XYPlot's drawRangeGridLines method, but I decided to go another way: to make it works you only need to change axis order because grid lines always depend on 0th axis (and its dataset). Make sure your axis has 0th index in plot axis collection.

```
NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis(name);
plot.setRangeAxis(0, axis);
```

I think it's easiest way at this moment.